# what is the context of bellow code

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

what is the actual meaning of these two statements?

```
waitFor(20) { 
  !userDropdown.text().contains("Sign In")
}

waitFor(20) {
  title ==~ /[\w\d \-\@()]+( - [\w\d \-]+){0,1} is using Bintray/
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `jQuery` when your code is Java?

Answer (score 2):

These look like Geb wait conditions:

```
waitFor(20) { 
   !userDropdown.text().contains("Sign In")
}
```

Wait for 20 seconds or a web element named userDropdown to **not** have the text "Sign In", whichever happens first.

***And***

```
waitFor(20) {
   title ==~ /[\w\d \-\@()]+( - [\w\d \-]+){0,1} is using Bintray/
}
```

wait for 20 seconds or the web page title to be some string ending "is using Bintray".